# What are the rules for geometrical transformations on entries of matrices that describe geometrical transformations?

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

<sub>This question may be a bit vague or broad, but it has bugged me ever since I learned about matrix transformations (mainly in the context of 3D computer graphics). I'm not a mathematician, so "simple" answers would be preferred. It might also be that I do not know the right keywords for a websearch, and any hint in this regard would also be appreciated.</sub>

---

Transformation matrices in 3D computer graphics are commonly $4 \times 4$ matrices, using homogeneous coordinates, so that they can describe more complex transformations like translations and projections.

The matrix describing a rotation around the z-axis in 3D is

$\begin{pmatrix}
cos \alpha & -sin \alpha & 0 & 0 \\
sin \alpha & cos \alpha & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix that describes a rotation about the x-axis is

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & cos \alpha & -sin \alpha & 0 \\
0 & sin \alpha & cos \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Obviously, the second matrix can be created from the first one: Treating the **matrix entries** as "points in 2D space", the transformation that is applied here is

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix translates the entries one step to the right, and one step down (assuming the "origin" at the upper left, in this case).

But it does not end there: The matrix for a rotation around the y-axis is

$\begin{pmatrix}
cos \alpha & 0 & sin \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-sin \alpha & 0 & cos \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

This can be created from the first matrix by applying

$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$

Which reflects the entries about the origin, translates the entries, and then scales them by a factor of 2.

<sub>(This may be a bit brittle, due to the discrete space, but should still make sense)</sub>

---

So the question is: What are the rules that govern these transformations?

<sup>(Or is this just an odd coincidence? I've read other questions, where these matrices have rather been described as [submatrices of a larger matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1547096/133498) ...)</sup>

Apologies if this turns out to be too broad, but I hope that the answer will eventually also answer these questions:

- Does this generalize to higher dimensions?
- Does this even apply to tensors?
- What other operations can be applied to *predefined* matrix entries that change the effect of the matrix in a "geometrically meaningful" manner? For example, a shear matrix can be converted into a translation matrix (using scaling by a factor of 0 and translating about 4 in x-direction), but the other way around is obviously not possible. The "reflection" about the origin in the last example could also be seens as a *rotation of the entries* around the z-axis, by 180° - maybe there are sensible transformations of the entries that involve rotations about 90°?